# Losing video when splitting mpg from middle

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Very new to ffmpeg so bear with me.

I'm trying to split an mpg in two pieces. It's a 4m 36s video. I want the first piece to be 170s and the second to be the rest. I have tried a bunch of different methods.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:2:50 output1.mpg
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:02:50 output2.mpg

ffmpeg -i input.mpg -t 170 -c copy output1.mpg -ss 170 -c copy output2.mpg
```

And a bunch of others. Every thing I've tried gives me a great first output1.mpg but output2.mpg is always missing the video. The file is saved as .mpg but it is only audio.

I found one option that said to try this for the 2nd piece.

```
ffmpeg -ss 170 -i input.mpg -t 176 -c copy output2.mpg
```

and that sometimes there are errors so to try:

```
ffmpeg -ss 170 -i input.mpg -t 176 output2.mpg
```

With the possibility that omitting '-c copy' might result in a good output.
So the first one above with '-c copy' gave me the same result, no video. The second option resulted in video and audio but the video was severely degraded in quality.

Can anyone help me? Why do I keep losing the video on the 2nd piece. I'm a newb but this seems pretty straight forward.

Here is the output from

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:2:50 output1.mpg

>ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:2:50 output1.m
pg
ffmpeg version N-62340-g1de8a4f Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 10 2014 22:08:28 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable
-zlib
  libavutil      52. 75.100 / 52. 75.100
  libavcodec     55. 58.103 / 55. 58.103
  libavformat    55. 36.103 / 55. 36.103
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'input.mpg':
  Duration: 00:04:36.48, start: 0.458744, bitrate: 3062 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3
], 4000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
Output #0, mpeg, to 'output1.mpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.36.103
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31,
4000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, 320 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg @ 00000000041fd4a0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0,
current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output
 file.
frame= 5096 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   61544kB time=00:02:50.00 bitrate=2965.6kbits
/s
video:54566kB audio:6641kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB mux
ing overhead: 0.550940%
```

and here is the output for

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:02:50 output2.mpg

>ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:02:50 output2.mpg
ffmpeg version N-62340-g1de8a4f Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 10 2014 22:08:28 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable
-zlib
  libavutil      52. 75.100 / 52. 75.100
  libavcodec     55. 58.103 / 55. 58.103
  libavformat    55. 36.103 / 55. 36.103
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'input.mpg':
  Duration: 00:04:36.48, start: 0.458744, bitrate: 3062 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3
], 4000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
Output #0, mpeg, to 'output2.mpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.36.103
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31,
4000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, 320 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 2364 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   31728kB time=00:01:19.07 bitrate=3286.8kbits/
frame= 3186 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   41828kB time=00:01:46.55 bitrate=3215.7kbits
/s
video:37440kB audio:4162kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB mux
ing overhead: 0.541575%
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output for the first and second commands.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the complete console output, and please format it properly.

Comment: I apologize, I did cut off some of the output thinking it was trivial, apparently not. Also, how would I "format it properly"?

Comment: Highlight the commands and console outputs and press `ctrl`+`k`, or highlight the commands and console outputs and click the code button above the editing box which looks like `{}`.

Comment: Should be all set and formatted, let me know if you need anything else...thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, I tried this splitting with .mov and it worked flawlessly. I also tried it with .mp4 and it worked but there was a timing "hiccup" so when I started the second output file there is a split second of the vlc cone.